# Root locus vs Matlab's root locus function

Tags: roots, matlab

Today during a lecture out teacher was demonstrating Matlab's `rlocus` function, but before that he decided to do it on chalkboard.

Below we have a simple transfer function:

$$
\dfrac{1}{(s^2+s+k)}
$$
We find roots for it using quadratic formula:
$$
s_1 = \dfrac{-1 + \sqrt{1-4k}}{2} = \dfrac{-1}{2} + \dfrac{\sqrt{4k-1}}{2}i
$$
$$
s_2 = \dfrac{-1 - \sqrt{1-4k}}{2} = \dfrac{-1}{2} - \dfrac{\sqrt{4k-1}}{2}i
$$

Given that $k=[0;\infty)$ we can plot these roots:
[image: Manual plot]

As you can see, when $k = 0, s_1 = -1 $ and $ s_2 = 0$. When $ k $ goes to infinity and beyond, $s_1$ goes up and $s_2$ goes down (on imaginary axis).

Now, when we tried to do this on Matlab using `rlocus` function and transfer function:
$$
\dfrac{1}{(s^2+s)},
$$
it gave us this plot:
[image: Matlab's rlocus plot]

Here $s_1$ goes down and $s_2$ goes up.

So, my question is - why? Did we do something wrong with calculations, equations or is it Matlab's fault?

Comment: Most likely this is an issue with the sign convention of the square root.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to understand that

$$
s_{1,2} = \dfrac{-1}{2} \pm \dfrac{\sqrt{4k-1}}{2}i
$$

You may choose $s_1 = \dfrac{-1}{2} + \dfrac{\sqrt{4k-1}}{2}i$ or $s_1 = \dfrac{-1}{2} - \dfrac{\sqrt{4k-1}}{2}i$. The choice is random and this is why root locus doesn't tell which pole that goes up or down.

Comment: Well... What was I thinking a few years ago :D ? Or rather, was I thinking at all...